# Algorithm for determining LR and TB order when not uniform

Tags: geometry, 2d, rectangles

wondering if anyone has any insight as to how to ascertain the order of differently sized rectangles from left to right and from top to bottom when they are not already aligned to any grid, and they are differently sized and/or rotated. Some might also be missing.

[image: How to determine L-R and T-B Order?]

As anyone can see from the illustration, the objects should be numbered as shown. But how, mathematically or programmatically, can I determine this? What is the logic? I don't even know what words to use to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a rather complex problem; maybe some algorithm already exists, IDK.

---

#### Approach 1: grid positioning.

One approach could start with trying to position the rectangles on a grid whose mesh size will have to be calculated; maybe a best fit to the size of the rectangles (H & W, or surface, maybe?)

Once a reasonable grid has been determined, it must be appropriately placed over the rectangles; maybe in such a way that minimizes row overlap and column overlap of the rectangles?

The last step would consist of traversing the grid row by row, and assigning a label to each rectangle; maybe based on the max common surface shared by a grid cell and a rectangle?

There will be many edge cases to identify and resolve.

---

#### Approach 2: sweep line.

Alternatively, a **sweep line** numbering of the rectangles from N, S, E, and W, and an appropriate weighting/averaging of the numbering of the rectangles from each direction, might give good results?
It may require several passes, after identifying what could be rows and columns, in order to find a "best fit".
This second approach is likely easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks, RM. It's a surprisingly difficult problem to solve with a program, when the eye does it so easily. One alternative I'm considering is how to use the center points of the rectangles to "band" vertically similar-positioned rectangles and then use a stable sort on each band (ie, row) by the leftness of each. Was thinking that if a point is within a distance of 1/2 of the height of a rect, then it's in the same row. (So I could assign a constant number to it for the stable sort.) Thanks for the ideas!